# PCManFM file size column is blank

Tags: pcmanfm

Just installed Lubuntu (Ubuntu 17.10) on a desktop. The default file manager, PCManFM seems to work well with the exception that the file size column doesn't populate, it remains blank. Every other column populates correctly.

PCManFM version is 1.2.5

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Mind sharing a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: I screwed up.  I have a lot of directories / folders.  They show up first without anything displayed in the size column.  Once I scrolled down to the actual files the size information was there.    I will delete this post  tomorrow so you have a chance to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders don't have a filesize.  If you have a ton of folders, that's why your column is blank.

Only files will have filesizes shown.  That's the problem you're running into (per your comments) - tons of folders, very few files, in the directory listings you're looking at in PCManFM.

Comment: Should I delete this question or is there a way to mark it resolved?

Comment: @GuyD'Amico There is a checkmark box underneath the voting buttons on my answer, to the left of the answer.  If you select that "checkbox" it'll select this answer as the proper answer and that will be equivalent to marking as 'resolved' as it will show in the system that your question has been answered and you accepted the given answer.  You could also ask us to delete the question, too, by flagging it.